# Gsutil stopchannel can not stop with AccessDeniedException

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I can not stopchannel with throwed exception: **AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller not owner of subscriptio**

I set permission in google developers console already with owner role, but still return exception.

gsutil version: 4.6

Comment: You need to use a service account for authentication, and one that is attached to the project where the channel was created. Are you using a service account?

Comment: Yes, I use service account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same service account that was used to create the channel, otherwise you get this error.
You can use the commands `gcloud auth list` to view the account list that you have in the instance. Use `gcloud config set account ACCOUNT` to set the service account as active.